# Can't access MySQL server, don't know the password of a root account

Tags: mysql, centos

For some reason beyond me I can't access the mysql server on a machine. I'm looking at an untouched MT (dv) server with CentOS 5. Any ideas on how to get the root going?

Comment: The edit kind of missed my point… The problem was that NO ROOT ACCOUNT EXISTED, at all, not that I couldn't access the mysql server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start (first stop the running one) your MySQL in safemode with skiped grant tables eg.:

```
safe_mysqld --user=mysql --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
```

Thereafter you should have access to your database without password and could create a new user/password.